# Django - get object based on ForeignKey field

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I need to get a single model object based on a set of fields one of which is a `ForeignKey`. So if I have the following models:

```
class Composer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    dates =  models.CharField()
    nationality = models.CharField()
    period = models.CharField()

class Symphony(models.Model):
    composer = models.ForeignKey('Composer', related_name="symphonies", null=True)
    date = models.CharField()
    key = models.CharField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
    num_movements = models.IntegerField()
```

how can I then retrieve a specific `Symphony` object based on its `composer` and `number` fields? I originally had composer as a simple `models.CharField()`, so I could just do:

```
Symphony.objects.get(composer='Bruckner', number=7)
```

So how do I do the equivalent using a `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work, but you should always use a unique value:

```
Symphony.objects.get(composer__name='Bruckner', number=7)
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/) you can find more usages for double underscore notation (`__`)

Comment: Hmmm, that does work (thanks), since the _combination_ of fields will always be unique... not sure if I should be wary of that though?

Comment: Indeed yes, that's the composer.

Comment: @ChrisM If the combination of number and componer's name will be unique in Symphony method I think you shouldn't worry about performing a .get() query.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to go with it. Thank you for the help/advice.